# Should I write custom validation or configurate spring correctly?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have an entity. I use rest controller.
My goal is to validate all fields in the coming JSON object. If I find one or more incorrect fields, I need to return all incorrect fields. How can I do it with spring?
Should I check every field in try - catch?

```
@Entity
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Size(min = 4, message = "Min length 4")
    private String first_name;

    @Size(min = 4, message = "Min length 4")
    private String last_name;

    @Size(min = 4, message = "Min length 4")
    private String fathers_name;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to annotate your client with `@RequestBody` and `@Valid` in rest method. Here is an example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/client")
public class ClientController {
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity createNewClient(@RequestBody @Valid Client client) {
        // insert client
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

If JSON data will be not valid, method will throw `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. You can handle it in such way:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> handleArgumentNotValidException(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        BindingResult bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();
        for (FieldError fieldError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
            errors.put(fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Comment: As far as I know the `ClientController` also has to be annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` for the exception handler to work, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @Lino If the handler is in the same class - yes, the class should be annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: Should I use try -catch in the method  createNewClient?
Now i see: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.model.entity.Client]
It doesn`t use ExceptionHandlerController

Comment: Have you registered ExceptionHandlerController? Something like `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {ExceptionHandlerController.class}) in your configuration